# User logout automatically when the browser is closed

Tags: 8, cookies

I need to logout a user if the browser is closed. I'm using Drupal 8.
I tried setting a session cookie in php. But the problem is the cookie should be '**httponly**' and '**secure**'.

Please suggest me the right method or is Drupal having such settings to achieve  this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I changed the **cookie_lifetime: 2000000** to **0** in *local.services.yml* file.

Then set the cookie in php by giving the last 2 arguments as 'true' ,this makes the cookie to be httponly and secure.

Thanks for your reference.